# Finding next and previous entries in an avl-tree

Tags: sorting

I am using an avl-tree to maintain a sorted list, e.g.:

```
(require 'avl-tree)

(let ((tree (avl-tree-create (lambda (a b) (string-lessp (car a) (car b))))))
  (avl-tree-enter tree (cons "b" 0))
  (avl-tree-enter tree (cons "a" 1))
  (avl-tree-enter tree (cons  "A" 2))
  (avl-tree-enter tree (cons  "d" 3))
  (avl-tree-enter tree (cons  "c" 4))
  (avl-tree-enter tree (cons  "C" 5))

  (avl-tree-flatten tree))
```

leads to this sorted list

```
((A . 2) (C . 5) (a . 1) (b . 0) (c . 4) (d . 3))
```

sorted by the car of each cons cell.

I can use a command like:

```
(avl-tree-member tree '("b"))
```

which returns the cell `(b . 0)`, but what I really want is to get the next or previous cons cell. I usually do this by finding the index of that cell in the sorted list, e.g. (`-find-index`) or (`cl-position`), but neither of these seem to take advantage of the sorted nature of the list. Is there a way to get the next/previous node out of avl-tree (or something similar)?

The real application of this is I have a list of hundreds of journal files sorted by date, and I want to be able to find the next or previous entry like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function to find the smallest entry strictly larger
than a given datum:

```
(defun avl-above (tree data)
  (let ((cmp (avl-tree--cmpfun tree)))
    (cl-labels ((above (node)
                   (when node
                     (if (funcall cmp data (avl-tree--node-data node))
                         (let ((left-above (above (avl-tree--node-left node))))
                           (if (and left-above
                                    (funcall cmp
                                             (avl-tree--node-data left-above)
                                             (avl-tree--node-data node)))
                               left-above
                             node))
                       (above (avl-tree--node-right node))))))
      (let ((node-above (above (avl-tree--root tree))))
        (and node-above (avl-tree--node-data node-above))))))
```

With your sample tree you'd have, for example:

```
(avl-above tree '(""))  ; => ("A" . 2)
(avl-above tree '("A")  ; => ("C" . 5)
...
(avl-above tree '("c")) ; => ("d" . 3)
(avl-above tree '("d")) ; => nil
```

(And, of course, to get the largest entry below a given datum you'd
write a completely symmetrical function.)

Note that this is even slightly better than being able to find the
next or previous entry after a given *entry*, you can also find the next
entry after a "non-entry". In your application, you could use this to
find the first journal file strictly after or before a given date.